# Messages on Mac displaying "Not Delivered" but message is being delivered

Tags: macos, messages, apple-id

I've tried logging out and back into my Apple ID account on my Mac, but some (not all) messages are showing the red exclamation point and "Not Delivered", but when I go to the same thread on my phone the message shows up as delivered. I've also checked some of them with one of the  people I was chatting with and they are being delivered.

This behavior started 2 or 3 weeks ago.

[image: one message with "! Not Delivered" and another with "Delivered"]

Comment: I do not have the same problem, but Messages.app on HighSierra is at least a little buggy. Sometimes I will send a text message through my Mac and it will go to the bottom, but when the other person replies it will go above my sent message. It will happen many times in a row, causing all my text messages to appear below the other person's. That's with text messages anyways.

Comment: after about a month (total) this stopped happening. I didn't do anything to solve it.

Comment: lol. did you update your macOS?

Comment: nope... nothing changed except the Not Delivered messages went away (well, they stopped appearing for new messages... the old ones are still there)

Comment: As for me the text messages are still in their glitched out order. I haven't texted from Messages.app recently, though.

Comment: I have the same problem too. Running Mac OS 10.13.3

Comment: Same issue with 10.13.4 - seems like they broke it as some point since it was working very well in previous releases.

Comment: Same here, taking it in tomorrow. will post if i find anything out

Comment: Same here as well. Very annoying.

Comment: on 10.13.6 having same issue

Answer (score 23):

What are the chances? I just helped someone with this an hour ago. This worked for her.

It appears that the messages database is corrupted. The only fix is to remove all messages.

From [here](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/05/clear-imessage-chat-history-in-mac-os-x/) with edits

- Quit out of Messages for Mac
- Go to Finder
- Hit Command+Shift+G to bring up the “Go To Folder” window
- Enter ~/Library/
- Move the Messages folder to Trash
- Restart the Computer
- Open Messages (**Nothing should be there**) and Test

If it works, great! Otherwise comment back here.

**Note: This will delete all messages from your Mac**

Comment: @TylerNZ If this helped you please upvote it by pressing the upward arrow to the left of the answer.

Comment: This is working so far on 10.13.6

Comment: I read _"Restart"_ as restart the messages application. It definitely means restart the computer!

Comment: @BillShirley Fixed.

Comment: This happens constantly to me ... never knew how to fix it! Thanks :)

Comment: @drfence, did this fix it permanently?  Or when you say constantly, you mean before you fixed it, or the problem keeps coming back after your fix?

Comment: @iJames yes I meant before this fix.  I haven't seen the issue since I followed the instructions above.

Comment: Now that I've changed my mac password, it's happening again.  iCloud didn't appear to be logged in correctly and I've fixed that but now I'm back to seeing "not delivered" in messages on Mac.

Comment: @drfence Try it again. Changing Mac password shouldn't have changed anything. What was wrong with iCloud? That may have caused it

Comment: I tried it again (2x) including reboot.  All messages are gone and when I try and send one I get the red !

Comment: It worked for me! This has bugged me for so long! THANKS

Comment: This did not work for me. I suspect it may be because I'm sending to 25 people. If I send the message to half of the people, then another message to the other half, it works.

Answer (score 7):

In my case I needed to `Settings->Messages->Text Message Forwarding` on the iPhone and deselect old devices there, plus select and confirm new one (the one I had trouble with).

Comment: This worked for me. I set up a new mac desktop and couldn't send iMessage to non-iPhone users. It was saying Not Delivered. Then I went to my iPhone and selected the new desktop under "Text Message Forwarding". Then I was able to send SMS to non-iPhone users from Desktop

Answer (score 4):

This solution worked for me by Ralph Johns from [Messages says "Not delivered"](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8059849) on Apple Support Communities. It seems to be the same problem as described here.

> AS a test deselect the iPhone Number as a Receive Item (it will close the Drop Down for Start Conversation From) so that the Mac can only Send (And Receive) from the Apple ID
>
> Now start a New Message.
>   in the "to" spot type in your iPhone Number in full including the country code.
>   (The My Details are not called up if you try your name as you are not expected to call yourself).
>
> Before send go to the iPhone > Settings > Messages > Send and Receive and deselect the Apple ID (don't log it out just deselect it).
>   This bit will stop any Sync copy showing up from the Send of the Apple ID on the Mac.
>
> Now send an iMessages from the Mac.
>
> Does the iPhone Receive it ?
>   If not then the Apple ID is not logging in properly on the Mac.
>   As a first Step try Logging out (Sign Out button) on the Mac version. Quit the app before relaunching the app and signing back in again.
>
> Repeat the test above.
>   If it still does not work then use this Users Tip [When the iMessages account will not Login](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-11291)
>   There is no way to speed up the last section where you have to contact Apple Support and get yourself moved up the chain of Responders until one can look at the Server and tell if your Apple ID when used from the Mac for iMessages is blocked. (your serial number is used for a device specific login so only one device can be block meaning the ID works in other places and devices).
>   You then still have to wait for the Engineers to reset your ID.

Comment: Another USELESS downvote without a helpful explanation on an answer that apparently actually worked.

Answer (score 2):

After loooooong time, I rebooted my mac and now looks like the "Not Delivered" messages issue is gone.

Comment: Same happened to me recently.  Just magically fixed itself after some period of time.

Comment: And this continues ... it comes and goes.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the Messages folder in ~/Library is a bit heavy handed.  Since I don't have this issue in all of my conversations, I decided to simply try deleting the problematic Conversation.  It appears to be working fine now.

Update:  The dreaded "Not Delivered" has returned.  Trying deleting the Messages folder this time.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from Reid Knapp got so many downvotes because of the very convoluted way the original cited author Ralph Johns - a veteran contributor to Apple Support Communities - usually wraps his suggestions in. I'd like to help by squeezing the juice of the Red Knapp's version re-cited from Ralph Johns based on my own experimentation trying to grasp Ralph Johns's thought process.  I run **macOS Mojave** and **iOS 12.4.1**.
You need to follow these steps:

1. On your iPhone go to *Settings-Messages-Send and Receive*.
2. Scroll down to the section "Start conversations From". If your phone number is checked, and if you have other types of incoming and outcoming messages (usually, it's e-mail addresses) listed under this section uncheck the phone number and check any of those e-mail addresses. This is a temporary measure.
3. Launch Messages on your Mac. Launch iOS Messages and try to send a message to yourself as a test. The message should appear in the macOS Messages conversation list without any hiccups and warnings.
4. In macOS Messages send a message to either yourself or another contact which is or isn't an iPhone user to test both iMessage and SMS delivery. If the message appears in iOS Messages on the fly and without a loading bar stuck then both devices are perfectly in sync.
5. Go back to the "Start conversations From" section of *Settings-Messages-Send and Receive* and put the checkmark back on your phone number.

Answer (score 0):

JBis answer above worked for me, but neither exactly, nor the first time...on my desktop I found signing out from Messages entirely, and then deleting both the Messages folder, and the preferences (com.apple.Messages.plist) from preferences folder, then restart and sign in again, worked straight away...however, on my laptop, not so, I had to do it about 3 or 4 times before it finally worked, and this also involved toggling "Settings->Messages->Text Message Forwarding" on and off on my phone, before and after the log out delete thing, and some "Start conversations From" toggling...I have no idea what sequence finally did it, but my point is don't give up, throw all these at it in various permutations and it eventually will work...madness, I know...